# How do I get the auto generated Id?

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, linq-to-sql

```
System
Language:C#
Database:SQL
IDE:C# Express 2010
```

I have a User object/class and db table. The user has multiple Adresses and I have already defined the Addresses table, how do I add and commit the address to the DB

I have created an Add function for the User (see below) The User class holds a List addresses

**User Class**

```
int id
string name
List<Address> adresses
```

**Table User**

```
id
name
addresses
```

**Table Addresses**

```
id 
address
user_id (FK)
```

I have the Add function in the User class to add User Objects, I stripped out the handling code to make it clearer on SO.

**My question is, how do I get the id of the User just added and add the Address into the database.
And
How do I define the FK on the Address Table**

```
 class User {

    public static bool Add(User user, UserOptions option = UserOptions.System)
    {
        //Instantiate the  DataClassesDataContext
        var db = DBContext.Create();

        //Make Sure User does not exist
        //returns true if no existing user
        if (Users.validateForAdd(user))
        {
           //Now add
           db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);

           //I assume I would get the id of the user just added but not sure how I do that

           db.SubmitChanges();
           return true;
        }

        //Failed to add
        return false;
    }
```

## Final Solution

Just thought I would post the final solution from the below answers and comments.

```
//
// Creating and setting the Objects
//
User user = new User(name="john doe");
EntitySet < Address >  adressList = new EntitySet<Address>();

adressList.Add(new Address("Residential Home");
adressList.Add(new Address("Holiday Home...");

user.address = adressList;

//
//Persisting to the DB
//
var db = new DataContext();
db.Results.InsertOnSubmit(result);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: The issue I have in setting a FK is that I cant see anywhere in the designer to create a FK. I went into Keys/Indexes but I cant see how to link the field to the User table_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I get the id of the User just added and add the
>   Address into the database.

The key is that you **do not need it**. Instead of assigning a foreign key field with an id, in Linq-2-sql you assign entities to eachother.

So instead of doing

```
somerelated_table.fk_user_id = user.id
```

you do

```
somerelated_table.user = user
```

Linq-2-sql will handle the proper assignment of the user.id when you call SubmitChanges. Plus as a bonus it will all be done in a single transaction. That is the beauty of linq-2-sql.

Comment: so when i persist my User object will it also write my addresses ?

Comment: so when I write
     db.Users.InsertOnSubmit(user);
     db.SubmitChanges();
It writes to both tables ? I tried this and I do not receive any data.

Comment: Thank you so much this have saved me hours of work. I got it to work thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can do one change to the above method Add. Instead of returning bool, you can return type int.

```
public static int Add(User user, UserOptions option = UserOptions.System)
 //Make Sure User does not exist
 //returns true if no existing user
 if (Users.validateForAdd(user))
 {
    ....
    ....
    //Instead of returning true you can return user.id
    return user.id;
 }
    //Instead of returning false you can return default value -1
    return -1;

}
```

So you can get the newly added user's id by calling method Add of User class and you can use that id to create List of addresses for the user.

Comment: yes I like that approach. any Ideas on how to set the constraint  FK on Addresses?

Comment: If you have defined foreign key, primary key constraint between user table and addresses table then LINQ data classes will provide the foreign key constraint by default. You can create one method inside User class: void AddAddress(int id,List<addresses>){ }. Inside the method you can pass id of the user for which you want to insert address. Before inserting address you can put check whether the id exists or not in the User table. Even if you don't check exception of Foreignkey violation will be thrown. You can either handle exception or you can validate the id before inserting it.

Comment: In the designer dbml, you can click on the class for example User and right  clicking it will give you option to create relationship. By creating relationship between user and Address you can create the constraint.

Comment: thanks @techfun - I found it, I was looking at the properties window when setting up the field before.